# Jquery removeClass doesn't work when trying to simulate an active button with a DIV

Tags: jquery, css, removeclass

Since i'm not good in CSS, I'm trying to simulate a pressed button behaviour (:active i think..) by adding a CSS "glow" class to a DIV with jquery addClass and then remove it after a little delay

this is how i write the code :

```
  $( ".cpUpbtnsclass" ).on('click', function() {

        console.log($( this ).attr('id')+" is clicked and a class will be added ! ");

           $( this ).addClass( "glow");

        setTimeout(function(){
            $( this ).removeClass( "glow");
        },300);
    });
```

and this is the class i want to add :

```
.glow {
box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 5px rgba(255, 255, 190, .75);
}
```

i see the glow effect added with addClass but then i don't see it disappearing after 300 ms.

Answer (score 2):

The timeout creates a new scope where `this` is no longer the element :

```
$( ".cpUpbtnsclass" ).on('click', function() {
    var self = this;

    $( this ).addClass( "glow");

    setTimeout(function(){
        $( self ).removeClass( "glow");
    },300);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
$(".cpUpbtnsclass").on('click', function () {
    var this1 = $(this); //cache your selector 
    this1.addClass("glow"); 
    setTimeout(function () {
        this1.removeClass("glow"); //use cached selector 
    }, 300);
});
```

---

The timeout creates a new scope so your `$(this)` is not element you think inside `setTimeout`

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function(){
    $(document).on('click', '.cpUpbtnsclass', function(){
        console.log($( this ).attr('id')+" is clicked and a class will be added ! ");
           $('.cpUpbtnsclass').addClass( "glow");
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('.cpUpbtnsclass').removeClass( "glow");
        },300);
    })
})
```

Demo here http://jsfiddle.net/N5Kk6/